# Why doesn't k-means give the global minima?

Tags: cluster-analysis, gradient, data-mining, k-means, convergence

I read that the k-means algorithm only converges to a local minima and not to a global minima. Why is this? I can logically think of how initialization could affect the final clustering and there is a possibility of sub-optimum clustering, but I did not find anything that will mathematically prove that.

Also, why is k-means an iterative process?
Can't we just partially differentiate the objective function w.r.t. to the centroids, equate it to zero to find the centroids that minimizes this function? Why do we have to use gradient descent to reach the minimum step by step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't mix the problem and the algorithm.

The k-means problem is finding the least-squares assignment to centroids.

There are multiple algorithms for finding a solution.

There is an obvious approach to find the global optimum: **enumerating all `k^n` possible assignments** - that *will* yield a global minimum, but in exponential runtime.

Much more attention was put to finding an approximate solution in *faster* time.

The Lloyd/Forgy algorithm is an EM-style iterative model refinement approach, that is guaranteed to converge to a *local* minimum simply because there is a finite number of states, and the objective function must decrease in every step. This algorithm runs in `O(n*k*i)` where `i << n` usually, but it may find a local minimum only.

The MacQueens method is technically not iterative. It's a single-pass, one-element-at-a-time algorithm that will not even find a local minimum in the Lloyd sense. (You can however run it multiple passes over the data set, until convergence, to get a local minimum too!) If you do a single pass, its in `O(n*k)`, for multiple passes add `i`. It may or may not take more passes than Lloyd.

Then there is Hartigan and Wong. I don't remember the details, IIRC it was a clever, more lazy, variant of Lloyd/Forgy, so probably in `O(n*k*i)`, too (although probably not recomputing all `n*k` distances for later iterations?)

You could also do a randomized alogrithm that just tests `l` random assignments. It probably won't find a minimum at all, but run in "linear" time `O(n*l)`.

Oh, and you can try different random initializations, to improve your chances of finding the global minimum. Add a factor `t` for the number of trials...

Comment: Good point.  I'd add don't mix cost function and the problem.  You can use all kinds of cost functions, not just squared error.

Answer (score 16):

Consider:

```
.   c   .

.   c   .
```

Where c is a cluster centroid. The algorithm will stop, but a better solution is:

```
.       .
c       c
.       .
```

With regards to a proof - You don't require a mathematical proof to prove that something isn't always true, you just need a single counter-example, as provided above. You can probably convert the above into a mathematical proof, but this is unnecessary and generally requires a lot of work; even in academia it is accepted to merely give a counter-example to disprove something.

The k-means algorithm is by definition an iterative process, it's simply the way it works. [The problem of clustering is NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), thus using an exact algorithm to calculate the centroids would take immensely long.

Comment: As I said, I can visualize how sub-optimum clustering can happen, and how the algorithm can stop at local minimum. But I needed mathematical proof [or a link to it]. Also, do you know whether calculating mathematically is either impossible/inefficient? If it isn't, are you saying that people would choose an iterative process over a single step process just because k-means is defined that way?

Comment: Edited answer appropriately.

Comment: Just a comment supporting this answer.  A counterexample IS a mathematical proof that a (sub-optimal) local minimum is possible.  There is no higher standard of proof that exists.  If you wanted to prove something stronger; maybe 40% of the time you get a bad solution or something, you'd have to precisely define what you mean and then prove it (hard).  But this is the correct answer to your question, to the highest standard of proof.